# Libgdx Ashley Entity Collision

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm attempting to make a game with libgdx and ashley. I have a basic understanding of both and was wondering how to handle a entity collision.

I saw a ContactListener in Box2D, but I am unsure of how to link this with entities in ashley.

I just want to prevent entities from passing through other entities.

Comment: actually it shouldn't make a difference, whether you use ashley (or any other ECS) or not. Collision detection should be separated and just depends on the type (not every entity can collide with ever other e.g. a plane and a submarine, so you might want to "filter" collisions) + hitbox of the entities.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have gotten collision detection working, however I have been unable to actually make the entities stop when they collide. I've tried just setting their velocity to 0, however gravity still acts on them and they will slowly pass through the stationary entitiy. Do you know of a better way I can make the entity stop when it collides?

Comment: Do you want to use the Box2D Physics engine? If thats the case, then you should read the [libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) and the tutorials on [iforce2d](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/). The tutorials on iforce2d are for c++, but the theory is the same for java (jBox2D) and C++. Also the examples should be understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach, that I implement myself:

1. Define interface CollisionListener:

   public interface CollisionListener {
       void onBeginContact(Body bodyA, Body bodyB);
   }
2. Create CollisionListenerSystem that register itself as world contact listener, and notifies your other systems about collisions:

   ```
   public class CollisionSystem implements ContactListener {
   private final List<CollisionListener> collisionListeners;

   public CollisionSystem(World world, List<CollisionListener> collisionListeners) {
       world.setContactListener(this);
       this.collisionListeners = collisionListeners;
   }

   @Override
   public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
       for (CollisionListener collisionListener : collisionListeners)
          collisionListener.onBeginContact(contact.getFixtureA().getBody(), contact.getFixtureB().getBody());
   ```
3. implement CollisionListener in any system, that should process collisions and pass it in the collisionListener list in CollisionSystem constructor